# Selenium c# MSTest Specflow execute tests to another device

Tags: selenium, postman, mstest, specflow, onactionexecuting

in my job we have a .NET custom application for testing, we are sending API Requests to another PC where the IIS Express web server is up and running with 81 port. after that test execution starts.

Now I've implemented the MSTest+Specflow project with selenium c# / VS19. on my local machine, it works perfectly, executing/extending reports.

I'm interested in which way can be achieved to send API Request or something to another PC that will starts executing tests. (I have access to that computer with RDP), I don't wanna connect via RDP every time I want to execute tests. for example, sending API Requests via postman to that IP address which will start execution automatically will be perfect.

Comment: Why not use a continuous integration server? There are a bunch of free and commercial ones available, and this is precisely what they were built for.

Comment: @GregBurghardt  I need that, manual testers can hit some button and test should be started. test will generate reports in slack channel.

Comment: CI servers give you buttons to press. They also have plugins that might allow you to post to a Slack channel.

Comment: @GregBurghardt thanks, i tried Jenkins, really good choice.